# open a file with a shell / bash script and get the filename

Tags: bash, shell

I want to create a script which handles specific files. It works so far with a simple open file dialog but I'd prefer the "open with" option where the file is opened with the script itself to do stuff.

So, what is the procedure here to let the file start the script and process the filename in it?

Comment: The usual process would be for the user to give the filename on the command line when invoking the script. For example `cat /etc/hosts`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution.  It can handle a list of only 1 file, or many, for a defined process.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE=`basename "${0}" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.$$.${BASE}"

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "\n Missing command line parameter to provide name of file containing list of files to process."
    exit 1
fi

FILE_CONTAINING_FILENAMES="$1"
if [ ! -s "${FILE_CONTAINING_FILENAMES}" ]
then
    echo "\n List file provided is empty.  Unable to proceed.\n"
    exit 1
fi

displayLog()
{
    if [ -s "${file_to_process}.log" ]
    then
        echo "\t Hit return to view log ...\c" ; read k
        more "${file_to_process}.log"
        echo "\t Hit return to continue ...\c" ; read k
    else
        echo "\t Nothing capture in logs ..."
    fi
}

displayErr()
{
    if [ -s "${file_to_process}.err" ]
    then
        echo "\t Hit return to view log ...\c" ; read k
        more "${file_to_process}.err"
        echo "\t Hit return to continue ...\c" ; read k
    else
        displayLog
    fi
}

processLoop()
{
    process_command "${file_to_process}" >"${file_to_process}.log" 2>"${file_to_process}.err"
    RC=$?
    if [ ${RC} -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "SUCCESS|${file_to_process}|"
        displayLog
    else
        echo "ERROR|RC=${RC}|${file_to_process}|" >&2
        displayErr
    fi
}

while [ true ]
do
    read file_to_process
    if [ -z "${file_to_process}" ] ; then  echo "\n Reached end of joblist.\n" ; exit 0 ; fi

    if [ -s "${file_to_process}" ]
    then
        processLoop
    else
        echo "EMPTY|${file_to_process}|" >&2
    fi
done <"${FILE_CONTAINING_FILENAMES}"
```